# Where should I put my sqlalchmey engine/connection object in django?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

I have already created a lot of models and query methods by sqlalchemy and now I want to build a website on it to provide services.

The problem is I am not sure where to put my engine in django code structure:

```py
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase")
```